# Index of List containing dictionaries of strings based on dictionary values

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I have a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` and I would like to get the index of the dictionary containing a specific value. I know this can be achieved with LINQ but I am totally lost as to how to get it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int index = listOfDictionaries.FindIndex(dict => dict.ContainsValue("some value"));
```

This returns -1 if the value is not contained in any of the dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure the element is contained then you can use this:

```
int idx = list.IndexOf(list.Single(x => x.ContainsValue("value")));
```

If you are not sure, you have to test if it is contained:

```
var match = list.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContainsValue("value"));
int idx = match != null ? list.IndexOf(match) : -1;
```

Either you use `ContainsKey` or `ContainsValue`, dependent on, if the value you search for is a key or a value.

Comment: thanks! +1 for the help and correct answer but I will select theonly112 answer as the correct one since it does not require an additional check to return -1 and does not throw error if key/value doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` is `dictionaries`:

```
var matches = dictionaries
    .Select((d, ix) => new { Dictionary = d, Index = ix })
    .Where(x => x.Dictionary.Values.Contains("specificValue")); // or ContainsValue as the Eric has shown

foreach(var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Index: " + match.Index);
}
```

If you just want the first match use `matches.First().Index`. This approach has the benefit that you also have the `Dictionary` and you have all matches if required.

Comment: Thank you although it is way more than I needed :) +1 for the help